Checkmarx Cross Site Scripting with JSENCODE
We have run the Checkmarx code scanner for our Visualforce page. In the Visualforce page controller, we have done the SOQL query and get the record name. After that, we are using that record name in the onClick of apex:commandButton in visualforce page. We are passing it as parameter of onClick javascript method. We have used JSENCODE while passing it as a parameter. But still Checkmarx is giving that as Stored XSS issue. See below screenshot.
How can we resolve this? Any ideas?

